# C++ initializing const

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, constants

I need to be able to initialize a const member inside the constructor, which counts up every time I create a new object. I was shown in school how its suppose to work, but I'm getting errors all the time. It's something to do with the copy constructor.

Here's the code and the compiler errors:

```
class kunde {
public:
    kunde(string name, int alter);
    kunde(const kunde& orig);
    ~kunde();
    int GetAlter() const;
    string GetName() const;
    const int GetKnr() const;

private:
    string name;
    int alter;

    const int knr;

    static int cnt;
    static int MaxKnr;
};
```

```
int kunde::cnt = 0;
int kunde::MaxKnr = 1000;

kunde::kunde(string name, int alter):knr(MaxKnr++) {
    this->name = name;
    this->alter = alter;
}

kunde::kunde(const kunde& orig):knr(MaxKnr++){
    this->name = orig.name;
    this->alter = orig.alter;
}

kunde::~kunde() {
}

int kunde::GetAlter() const {
    return alter;
}

string kunde::GetName() const {
    return name;
}

const int kunde::GetKnr() const {
    return knr;
}
```

```
        main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
    main.cpp:35:15: error: use of deleted function 'kunde& kunde::operator=(const kunde&)'
          v[0] = v[1];
               ^
    In file included from main.cpp:17:0:
    kunde.h:19:7: note: 'kunde& kunde::operator=(const kunde&)' is implicitly  deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class kunde {
           ^~~~~
    kunde.h:19:7: error: non-static const member 'const int kunde::knr', can't use default assignment operator
```

Comment: Does `knr` need to be const?

Comment: So, what is supposed to happen to `knr` when you assign one object to another?

Comment: unfortunately yes. the prof wants it to be like that.

Comment: If you get build errors then please show them to us. Copy-paste them (as text) into the question body, in full and complete.

Comment: knr is suppose to increase by one when an object is copied.

Comment: The `knr` of the source or the destination is supposed to increase?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You need to figure out what knr is supposed to mean. And why declare it const if you want to change it? Once you know how it is supposed to work, you can fix the assignment operator.

Comment: Regarding the constness of `knr`, if it's a kind of serial-number to uniqely identify a "kunde" (which I suppose is German for "customer"?) then it doesn't make sense. If you make a copy, both copies are of the *same* customer, are they not? Having different customer numbers for the same customer just doesn't make sense.

Comment: knr is suppose to be an account number. each time you create an object it creates a new const account number which stays.

Comment: Implement the assignment operator.

Comment: Your issue is with the _assignment operator_, not the copy constructor.  Your error refers to code `v[0] = v[1]` that you have not shown us.  If you need `knr` to be `const`, default assignment is not possible because _assigning_ implies _changing_ and `const` forbids changing.

Comment: The default  copy-assignment operator is deleted due to the `const` nature of `knr`. So implement an override that doesn't touch that member.

Comment: v is just a vector. the thing is i need to be able to create a new object with that knr const and afterwards put it into an vector and i have to be able to delete a position within the vector by shifting each element to the left. how could I achieve this otherwise?

Comment: vector has to be able to move thing around. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector the underlying type must be copy assignable. You can't use std::vector<kunde> because you can't copy assign. You can have std::vector<std::unique<kunde>>, or you can "fix" the assignment operator to change the "const" knr (in which case it's not really const). It might make more sense to make knr private, and provide a const accessor.

Comment: Regarding `const int GetKnr() const;` declaring a variable returned by value as `const` isn't necessary. The caller can't do any damage to the source object with a copy. `int GetKnr() const;` is all the `const`-ness you need for this one.

Comment: @user3821856: First you said that `knr` must increase when the object is copied by assignment. Then you said that it is supposed to be set when the object is created and then stay the same. This is self-contradictory. You need to make up your mind and meaningfully describe what `knr` is and when it is supposed to change (or snot to change).

Comment: In 20 years of C++, I've never heard of such a thing as "initalize a const initialize"...I assume there is a tremendous language barrier. I also hope the OP realizes that having a const member is contradictory to "which counts up"...you cannot alter the value of a const member after the class has been initialized. I think that part is much more than just a language barrier.

Comment: A const value can be initialized in the constructor. It can be based on a class static "counter" which counts up. Nothing unusual about that, if you stick to it. But then they want to change it, which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

> `knr` is suppose to be an account number. each time you create an object it creates a new const account number which stays.

As stated in comments, since `knr` is `const`, the compiler cannot generate a default copy-assignment `operator=` for the class, which is exactly what the compiler is complaining about for the `v[0] = v[1];` statement:

> note: 'kunde& kunde::operator=(const kunde&)' is implicitly  deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

`const` members cannot be re-assigned once initialized, thus cannot be copied.

The elements in a `vector` must be [`CopyAssignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) and [`CopyConstructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) (at least until C++11), but your class does not have a viable copy-assignment `operator=`, so it is not `CopyAssignable` (and it is not [`MoveAssignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) in C++11 either, since a viable move-assignment `operator=` can't be generated, either).

The solution is to implement a copy-assignment `operator=` (and optionally a move-assignment `operator=`) that ignores `knr`, eg:

```
class kunde {
public:
    kunde(string name, int alter);
    kunde(const kunde& orig);
    kunde(kunde&& orig);
    ...
    kunde& operator=(const kunde& rhs);
    kunde& operator=(kunde&& rhs);
    ...

private:
    string name;
    int alter;
    const int knr;
    ...
};
```

```
kunde::kunde(string name, int alter)
    : knr(MaxKnr++), name(name), alter(alter)
{
}

kunde::kunde(const kunde& orig)
    : knr(MaxKnr++), name(orig.name), alter(orig.alter)
{
}

kunde::kunde(kunde&& orig)
    : knr(MaxKnr++), name(std::move(orig.name)), alter(orig.alter)
{
}

kunde& kunde::operator=(const kunde& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        name = rhs.name;
        alter = rhs.alter;
        // CAN'T BE DONE, SO IGNORE IT
        // knr = rhs.knr;
    }
    return *this;
}

kunde& kunde::operator=(kunde&& rhs)
{
    name = std::move(rhs.name);
    alter = rhs.alter;
    // CAN'T BE DONE, SO IGNORE IT
    // knr = rhs.knr;
    return *this;
}
```